# Pulling out a maximum term from an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, functional-inequalities, holder-inequality

Suppose $g$ is nonnegative on $[0,1]$.  Is the following true?

$$ \left| \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx\right| \leq \|g\|_\infty \left| \int_0^1 f(x) dx\right| $$

This would be like Holder's inequality, except without pulling the absolute value into the integral of $f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g = \mathbf{1}_{[0, 1/2]}$ and $f = \mathbf{1}_{[0, 1/2]} - \mathbf{1}_{(1/2, 1]}$. Then the left-hand side is $1/2$ while the right-hand side is $1 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! So if $f$ were nonnegative as well, it looks like the inequality would hold?

Comment: @900edges Yes, if $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative, then you can ignore the absolute values, and the inequality then becomes very simple.